# HttpClient can't connect to database

Tags: java, php, android

I'm having some trouble with the connection to my database, I could need some help to see if it's the .java file that is wrong or my .php file. The result right now is "couldn't connect to database"

.php file http://pastebin.com/9fMmzprd

.java:

```
package com.example.stolle.httpclient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class contact extends Activity {

    TextView resultView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        getData();
    }
    public void getData(){
        String result ="";
        InputStream isr = null;
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new
                    HttpPost("http://stolle.se.preview.citynetwork.se/kontaktApp/read_allcontacts.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection"+e.toString());
            resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
        }


        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
        }

        try {
            String s = "";
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                s = s+
                        "id : "+json.getInt("id")+"\n"+
                        "name : "+json.getString("name")+"\n"+
                        "mail : "+json.getString("mail")+"\n"+
                        "company :"+json.getString("company")+"\n\n";
            }

            resultView.setText(s);

        }

        catch (Exception e){
//to do handle exception
            Log.e("Log_tag", "Error Parsing Data" + e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contact, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Logcat shows any error??  Your php file working fine and reading all data. I checked it. ;) @Filip

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with PHP. Your PHP file is working good. Your error is at httppost request section. You dont have a `setEntity` which is required. Look [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) for details.

I can give a example of Httppost request with name value pair.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test","123"));   
 try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("URL");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
}
```

Comment: But what if I don't wanna use POST? may i change it to GET?

Comment: Try with passing dummy data. Also refer httpurlconnection  method..